# Can AppLocker be used to block all executables downloaded from a browser?

Tags: windows

I know Windows sets an ADS when a file is downloaded from the Internet. Can I use that to tell AppLocker to block all executables that are downloaded from a browser? If so, how?

Comment: I just want to make sure I understand.  By ADS you mean `alternate data stream` correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct

Comment: Based on preliminary research `AppLocker ` does not appear to be ADS aware, it also looks likes its not only not aware of how to handle that data, it gets confused by said data.  It does look like that perhaps this might have been also just a [bug](http://www.postseek.com/meta/67f96f9bf56345fbac846b26aaa8d53d) with office.  What is clear is you can't use the data by itself.